# Разрешение приложений

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-permissions

Есть ли способ каким-либо образом доставать для каждого разрешения для приложения краткую информацию об этом разрешений?

`PackageInfo packageInfo =  packageManager.getPackageInfo(applicationInfo.packageName, 
 PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
String [] permissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions`

Здесь возвращается массив строк, но как теперь достать подобное краткое описание?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Если пользователь один раз отказал в доступе, то это можно отследить

```
  if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    /*если отклонили разрешение вызываем диалог с объяснением
                     * для чего нужно оно*/

                }
```

После чего из AlertDialog при позитивном нажатии идет запрос на разрешение.
Конечно можно сам запрос кастомизировать, но по моему это лишнее.

Comment: если честно, из ответа ничего не понял. Попытаюсь правильно сформулировать вопрос: Мне возвращается массив строк с названием разрешения, при клике на одну из них, нужно, чтобы выводилось диалоговое окно, но где хранится информация, для для чего именно это разрешение нужно?